# Create a subView using CGPath and than adding UIPanGestureRecognizer on that subview

Tags: ios, swift3, subview, uipangesturerecognizer, evernote

I have seen several answers about adding a `GestureRecognzier` to subViews but my problem is that I don't have the subView's frame available beforehand. I am drawing a `CGPath` and at the `Touches Ended` method, I want to create a new `subView` with frame equal to `CGPath` bounding box. After that, I want to drag that `subView` with `PanGestureRecognizer`. I am trying to implement `Evernote crop` functionality where the user selects a certain area of view and move it to other position. Is this the right approach to that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite understand the relationship between `UIGestureRecognizer` and `.frame`. you can simply add `UIGestureRecognizer` to object, once its init work finished.
Try to add gesture in `TouchEnd` method directly after drawing subview.

```
import UIKit

class GestureResearchVC: UIViewController{

    var subViewByCGPath: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func createSubView(){
        //creat subview
        subViewByCGPath = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
        subViewByCGPath?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 50,y: 50), radius: CGFloat(20), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        subViewByCGPath?.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.view.addSubview(subViewByCGPath!)

        //add pan gesture to subViewByCGPath
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureAction(rec:)))
        subViewByCGPath?.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if subViewByCGPath == nil {
            print("touch end once")
            createSubView()
        }else{
            print("touch end repeatedly")
        }
    }

    func panGestureAction(rec: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        print("pannnnnnn~")
        let transPoint = rec.translation(in: self.view)
        let x = rec.view!.center.x + transPoint.x
        let y = rec.view!.center.y + transPoint.y

        rec.view!.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        rec.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: self.view)

        //distinguish state
        switch rec.state {
            case .began:
                print("began")
            case .changed:
                print("changed")
            case .ended:
                print("ended")
            default:
                print("???")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How Can I use GestureRecognizer states such as . began or .cancelled in this code. When the pan is ended I want to perform another action. or Shortly Can I check when the pan is ended on the subView. Thanks

Comment: You can use `.state` property, browse my code (edited)

Comment: If I want to create subViewByCGPath and add it to another subView(let's say DrawingView). Which changes would you recommend in panGestureAction function for translation then?

Comment: @HussnainWaris  Mostly, pan gesture is used to continuously update object position. In this case,     demo already done. If the target is to add that subview(created by CGPath) to another subview(DrawingView) when panGestureAction function called,  you should use tapGesture and implement that logic when touch end.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I need to add subViewbyCGPath to another SubView(DrawingView) and than add PanGesture on  subViewByCGPath.

 `func panGestureAction(rec: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        print("pannnnnnn~")
        let transPoint = rec.translation(in: TouchDrawing.view)
        let x = rec.view!.center.x + transPoint.x
        let y = rec.view!.center.y + transPoint.y
        rec.view!.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        rec.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: TouchDrawing.view)
} `